# Create the logic game Mastermind using a GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, game, tkinter

This code uses a single Mastermind class to hold everything needed as a tkinter widget that inherits from tk.Frame. Is this the best way of organising something like this or would it be better to use two classes - one for the game logic and one for the GUI?

The code itself seems messy, although I have no experince with tkinter applications larger than a Hello World script, so ways to clean it up and/or reorganise it would be greatly appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import choices
import itertools as it


class Mastermind(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, holes=5, colours=8, guesses=12, bg="white", fg="black", **kwargs):
        self.numberOfHoles = holes
        self.numberOfColours = colours
        self.numberOfGuesses = guesses
        self.bg = bg 
        self.fg = fg
        self.master = master
        self.colours = ["#9E5D00", "#FF0000", "#FF7F00", "#FFFF00", "#00FF00",
                        "#0000FF", "#FF00FF", "#8C44FF", "#FFFFFF", "#000000"][:self.numberOfColours]
        self.reset_cycles()
        self.answer = choices(self.colours, k=self.numberOfHoles)
        super().__init__(self.master, bg=self.bg, **kwargs)
        print(self.answer)
        self.create_gui()


    def create_gui(self):
        self.allGuesses = [tk.Frame(self, bg=self.bg) for _ in range(self.numberOfGuesses)]
        self.allMarks = [tk.Frame(self, bg=self.bg) for _ in range(self.numberOfGuesses)]
        self.answerFrame = tk.Frame(self, bg=self.bg)
        self.answerCover = tk.Frame(self, bg=self.fg, relief=tk.RAISED)
        self.allGuessPins = [[tk.Label(self.allGuesses[i], width=2, height=1, bg="grey", relief=tk.SUNKEN)
                             for _ in range(self.numberOfHoles)]
                             for i in range(self.numberOfGuesses)]
        self.allMarkPins = [[tk.Label(self.allMarks[i], width=1, height=1, bg="lightgrey", relief=tk.SUNKEN)
                             for _ in range(self.numberOfHoles)]
                             for i in range(self.numberOfGuesses)]
        self.answerPins = [tk.Label(self.answerFrame, width=2, height=1, bg=colour, relief=tk.RAISED) for colour in self.answer]
        self.guessBtn = tk.Button(self, text="Guess", command=self.next_guess, bg=self.bg, fg=self.fg)
        self.activeGuess = 0

        for rowIndex in range(self.numberOfGuesses):
            for holeIndex in range(self.numberOfHoles):
                self.allGuessPins[rowIndex][holeIndex].grid(row=0, column=holeIndex, padx=1, pady=4)
                self.allMarkPins[rowIndex][holeIndex].grid(row=0, column=holeIndex, padx=1, pady=4)
            tk.Label(self, text=str(rowIndex+1), bg=self.bg, fg=self.fg).grid(row=self.numberOfGuesses-rowIndex, column=0)
            self.allGuesses[rowIndex].grid(row=rowIndex+1, column=1)
            self.allMarks[rowIndex].grid(row=rowIndex+1, column=3)

        for i, a in enumerate(self.answerPins):
            a.grid(row=0, column=i, padx=1)

        tk.Label(self, text="   ", bg=self.bg).grid(row=0, column=2)
        tk.Label(self, text="   ", bg=self.bg).grid(row=0, column=4)
        for a in [tk.Label(self.answerCover, width=2, height=1, bg=self.fg) for _ in range(self.numberOfHoles)]:
            a.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=1)

        self.answerCover.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=15)
        self.guessBtn.grid(column=1, row=999, pady=10)
        self.next_guess(start=True)


    def next_guess(self, start=False):
        # Check there are no blanks
        for colour in self.get_pin_colours():
            if colour == "grey" and not start:
                return None

        # Stop responding to mouse button and remove highlighting
        self.reset_cycles()
        self.allGuesses[self.activeGuess].config(bg=self.bg)
        for pin in self.allGuessPins[self.activeGuess]:
            pin.unbind("<1>")
            pin["cursor"] = ""

        # Add the mark pins for the guess
        score = self.score_guess(self.get_pin_colours(), self.answer)
        if not start and len(score) != 0:
            score = self.score_guess(self.get_pin_colours(), self.answer)
            for i, pin in enumerate(self.allMarkPins[self.activeGuess]):
                if i > len(score)-1:
                    break
                pin.config(bg=score[i], relief=tk.RAISED)

        # Check for a win
        if score == ["Black" for _ in range(self.numberOfHoles)]:
            self.answerCover.grid_forget()
            self.answerFrame.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=15)
            self.guessBtn["command"] = None
            return None

        # Move the guess up 1, bind mouse button and highlight row
        try:
            self.activeGuess -= 1
            self.allGuesses[self.activeGuess].config(bg=self.fg)
            for i, pin in enumerate(self.allGuessPins[self.activeGuess]):
                pin.bind("<1>", lambda event, i=i: self.change_pin_colour(event, i))
                pin["cursor"] = "hand"
        except IndexError:
            raise NotImplementedError()
            # add lose condition


    @staticmethod
    def score_guess(guess, answer):
        answer = answer.copy()
        blacks = ["Black" for secret, guess_item in zip(answer, guess) if secret == guess_item]
        whites = []
        for guess_item in guess:
            if guess_item in answer:
                answer[answer.index(guess_item)] = None
                whites.append("White")
        return blacks + whites[:-len(blacks)]


    def get_pin_colours(self):
        return [pin["bg"] for pin in self.allGuessPins[self.activeGuess]]

    def change_pin_colour(self, event, i):
        event.widget.config(bg=next(self.colourCycles[i]), relief=tk.RAISED)

    def reset_cycles(self):
        self.colourCycles = it.tee(it.cycle(self.colours), self.numberOfHoles)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Mastermind")
    x = Mastermind(root)
    x.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello and welcome to CodeReview! (And thank you for using British spelling ;-) )

You already identified the biggest thing -

> it [would] be better to use two classes - one for the game logic and one for the GUI

Separation of concerns and loose coupling will be improved, in turn improving maintainability and testability, when those are separated. Other things:

### snake_case

`numberOfHoles`, by Python convention, should be `number_of_holes`.

### Use type hinting

Take a read through [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) and do some Googling; this will help out with program correctness and static analysis.

### Fix up your indentation

You have `@staticmethod` on a top-level function. Either this shouldn't have that annotation, or it should live in the class. I think you've just failed to indent all of your member variables.

### Repetition

```
["Black" for _ in range(self.numberOfHoles)]:
```

can be

```
["Black"] * self.numberOfHoles
```

### State representation

You're using the strings `Black` and `White` to represent a player. There are better choices - maybe a boolean (false for black, true for white) or an enum - see https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

Or, you could have two instances of a class Player, and track your state like that. But don't use a string.

### Redundant return

```
return None
```

can be deleted if it's at the end of a function, or written as `return` if it's to early-terminate a loop.

### Simplify logic

```
if i > len(score)-1
```

can be

```
if i >= len(score)
```

However, there's a bigger problem. This loop:

```
    for i, pin in enumerate(self.allMarkPins[self.activeGuess]):
        if i > len(score)-1:
            break
        pin.config(bg=score[i], relief=tk.RAISED)
```

should just be

```
for i, pin in enumerate(self.all_mark_pins[self.active_guess][:len(score)]):
    pin.config ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this breakdown. I did just mess up the indentation when I posted the question. The reason I was using "Black" and "White" instead of True and False was that it was being passed into tkinter directly to set the pin colour. Adding something to convert True to "Black" etc. seemed to be pointless to me.

Comment: @SImon It isn't pointless; converting from business logic representation to presentation is a normal and useful thing to do.